# Horizontal menu wont hide after first run

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I have a horizontal animated menu that has a strange behavior because it works fine only first time, after that the expandable menu is not animated and I don't understand why the 
`ul#nav ul{display:none;}` is not applied any more... this is jQuery function that I use for animation.

```
function mainMenu(){
$('ul#nav').find('> li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul')
        .stop(true, true)
        .slideDown('slow');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
function mainMenu(){
$('ul#nav').find('> li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul')
        .stop(true, true)
        .slideDown('slow');
    }, function(){ $(this).find('ul').hide(); });
};
```

the problem is that the first time you have your `<ul>` hidden so it's working just fine. After slideDown(), the `<ul>` becomes visible but when you move your mouse, you just change the left attribute, not the display. Basically, the `<ul>` is already visible so slideDown is not working.